# Trouble with aligning text in ZStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

[image: picture of user interface]

I want the white text on the picture to be on the bottom of each list-element.
I know this a very foolish question, but i have literally tried everything.

Here´s the code:

```
ZStack {
    Image(uiImage: "car_pic").resizable()
        .frame(width: 380.0, height: 250.0)
                            
    HStack (alignment: .bottom, spacing: 50){
        NavigationLink(destination: VideoShow(selectedVideoShow: streng)) {
            Text("25-06-2020").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .default)).foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

How may I align it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `alignment` argument to the `ZStack`

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
    ,,,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the link in a `VStack` and use `Spacer()` to push it to the bottom:

```
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Image(uiImage: "car_pic").resizable()
        .frame(width: 380.0, height: 250.0)
                            
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        NavigationLink(destination: VideoShow(selectedVideoShow: streng)) {
            Text("25-06-2020").font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .default)).foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To left align the text instead of centering on the image, also change `ZStack` to `ZStack(alignment: .leading)`

Comment: Thanks @henrik-dmg.  For some reason, I never saw your comment nor any of the other answers which is why I kept editing mine trying things.  I came up with both your suggestion and the accepted answer independently, but many minutes later and added to my answer only to see that it was already here.  I don't know why the web page didn't show any of the other answers or your comment.  I've never had that happen before.

Comment: I had initially misread the question and therefore deleted my answer. All good though :)